# Changing an individual foreach array field tag input type

Tags: php

I have a field in foreach password field that needs asterisks in it but it is in a foreach build, I change the input type to "password but they all get changed.

I tried this but no dice:

**Code**:

```
foreach($rows as $field => $label)

echo "<div class='field'><label for='$field'>$label</label>
<input id='$field' name='$field' type='text' value='".@$$field."'
size='25%' maxlength='65' /></div>\n";
```

I tried using this :

```
if ($field == "password" ){
echo "<input id='$field' name='$field' type='password' value='".@$$field."'
size='25%' maxlength='65' /></div>\n"}
```

nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I put it inside if else statement.

```
$fields = [
    'text' => 'text label',
    'password' => 'pass label'
];

foreach ($fields as $field => $label) {

    if ($field == "password" ){
        echo "<div class='field'><label for='$field'>$label</label><input id='$field' name='$field' type='password' value=$field
        size='25%' maxlength='65' /></div><br />";
    } else {
        echo "<div class='field'><label for='$field'>$label</label>
        <input id='$field' name='$field' type='text' value=$field
        size='25%' maxlength='65' /></div><br />";  
    }   
}
```